# Is there a way to get the Android button pressed state?

Tags: android, android-button

The Android Button has only `ACTION_UP`, `ACTION_DOWN`, and `ACTION_MOVE` states, so I can't hold down the `Button` for a long time...
As a simple example, I want to make a top, bottom, left and right Button and move the square box displayed on the screen (`drawRect` drawn on `Canvas`). I want to implement a state in which the box continues to rise when the upper button is pressed.

What listener should be attached to the `Button`??

Comment: you need a boolean, set it to true on action down, set it to false on action up

Answer (score 2):

you can change the box position when you press down, and when the ACTION_UP event happened, stop box position change

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question is, how do I catch the button pressed? ACTION_DOWN captures only the moment the button is pressed, ACTION_UP captures the moment when the button is released, and ACTION_MOVE captures the moment when the finger is dragged while the button is pressed.

Comment: ACTION_DOWN event only excute once when you touch, then ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP ...

Answer (score 0):

I would check out threads for this:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/creating-and-starting-threads.html

Comment: ```ACTION_DOWN``` catches only one instance of the button being pressed. I couldn’t hold the button pressed.

Comment: Edited original answer.